# macOS NO new file here, advantages?

Tags: macos, finder, file

On macOS Finder we don't have a `new file here` by default. So they created it somewhere else (https://langui.net/new-file-here/) and people have to pay extra for that.

In principle it seems to me a `new file here` is a good thing to have. But many times apple cut stuff out, and then we notice we actually don't need it.
I trying to understand if that idea is being applied to the missing `new file here` case.
However I'm having a hard time to understand the benefits of not having a `new file here`.

What are the advantages of not having a `new file here`?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely to get closed as opinion-based, but I'd ask "What's the perceived benefit of being able to create a blank file to then have to open it in a separate action?"
Why not just generate new files in the application you're going to use them in?

You can, if you need for arcane or esoteric purposes, easily create a blank file in Terminal with `touch`.

Comment: I'd like to point out that if you want this, it's trivial with Automator.

Comment: @MarcWilson, mind to leave a link with the instructions?

Comment: @Tetsujin "What's the perceived benefit of being able to create a blank file to then have to open it in a separate action?" It seems to be faster in case of a txt/md file.

Comment: Find location, right-click>new>find file type from list, launch file to app, (type), save. As opposed to Launch app, Cmd.N, (type), find location, save. Not seeing how that's faster.